# Which is the best way to rig a model with lots of clothes and details?

Tags: animation, rigging, armature, weight-painting

I found that parenting with envelope weights is not a good idea, and the with automatic weights option simply doesn't work.
With this, I just discovered that maybe a good idea is to separate your model into several pieces (so you can use the automatic weights option) and then join all of them together again.
Is there any other way or something? What do you think?

Sorry if this shouldn't go here since it looks like a debate more than a simple question, but I don´t know where to post this. Anyway, maybe this can help others anyway!

Comment: Can you add a picture of your model? so we can evaluate the complexity of the task.